# Spark - Issue with select statement run multiple times

Tags: java, apache-spark

Small question regarding Spark please.

What I would like to achieve is quite straightforward:
I have a Spark cluster with 10 executors which I would like to utilize.
I need to run a query selecting 10 rows from the DB.

My expectation is something like: select 10 rows, results are rows 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10.
Then apply a map operation on each row. Something like executor 1 applies the operation Op to row one of the row, executor 2 applies the operation Op to another row, etc...

Note, my operation OP have proper logging and proper KPI.

Therefore, I went to try this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String query = "SELECT TOP(10) id, last_name, first_name FROM mytable WHERE ...";
        final SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate();
        final Properties   dbConnectionProperties   = new Properties();
        dbConnectionProperties.putAll([...]);

        final Dataset<Row> topTenDataSet = sparkSession.read().jdbc(someUrl, query, dbConnectionProperties);
        topTenDataSet.show();
        
        final Dataset<String> topTenDataSetAfterMap = topTenDataSet.repartition(10).map((MapFunction<Row, String>) row -> performOperationWithLogAndKPI(row), Encoders.STRING());

        LOGGER.info("the count is expected to be 10 " + topTenDataSetAfterMap.count() + topTenDataSetAfterMap.showString(100000, 1000000, false));
        sparkSession.stop();
    }
```

With this code, there is a strange outcome.

Both `topTenDataSet.show();` and `topTenDataSetAfterMap.count()` shows 10 rows, happy.

But I look at the logs from the operation Op `performOperationWithLogAndKPI`  I can see much more than 10 logs, much more than 10 metrics. Meaning, I can see executor 1 performing 10 times the operation, but also executor 2 performing 10 times the operation, etc.

It seems like each executor run its own "SELECT TOP(10) from DB" and applies the map function on each dataset.

May I ask: did I made some mistake in the code?

Is my understanding not correct?

How to achieve the expected, querying once, and having each executor apply a function to part of the result set?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to execute multiple actions on the same Dataset, try to [cache it](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#cache--). This way the select top 10 results query should be executed only once:

```
final Dataset<Row> topTenDataSet = sparkSession.read().jdbc(someUrl, query, dbConnectionProperties);
topTenDataSet.cache();
topTenDataSet.show();
final Dataset<String> topTenDataSetAfterMap = topTenDataSet.repartition(10).map((MapFunction<Row, String>) row -> performOperationWithLogAndKPI(row), Encoders.STRING());
```

Further info [here](https://medium.com/pecan-ai/caching-spark-dataframe-how-when-79a8c13254c0)

Comment: This is indeed the correct answer. This .cache() operation is quite mysterious. With that said, after I .cache() everything, result = ok